# The fastest way to get attribute values on product listing

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking for the most effective way to get configurable product attribute values on product listing pages, for example color values for a product (from assigned simple products)

Currently looking into utilising `catalog_product_flat_n` table for this purpose, but perhaps there is an easier or more correct approach to do this? I'm trying to avoid using

```php
$product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray()
```

on every product, as this will be very slow

Thanks

Comment: The correct answer to your question will vary based on what you mean by "most effective" and by the attribute data you want (position, label, etc).

Comment: If you are only dealing with a single product in the rendering scope, this is exactly what is happening in the View-injected configurable `product.info` block.

Comment: I'm aiming to retrieve color values like Black, Green etc. and it's not for single product unfortunately, but for category product listing. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, so I created my own resource model for getting data from flat tables, look into code below

```
  <?php

    class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_Colors extends
        Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
    {
        protected $_storeId;

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('catalog/product_flat', 'entity_id');
            $this->_storeId = (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        }

        public function getData($entityId)
        {
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $select = $resource->getConnection('core_read')->select();
            $select
                ->from($this->getTable(array('catalog/product_flat', $this->_storeId)), '*')
                ->where('entity_id = :entity_id');



            $result = $resource->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($select, array('entity_id' => $entityId));

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: With this in place, what do you change in the category template?